# Moderator deleting answers without marking duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers, moderation

Recently I noticed that a moderator deleted some answers from these questions:

- [Getting Vevo video information and download links from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839004)
- [Get YouTube video title with video ID in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110803)
- [Trying to fetch YouTube video title and description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573455)
- [Get YouTube video title in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664482)

With this message:

> Please [don't post identical answers to multiple
> questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good
> answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If
> the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the
> question*.

So the moderator believes that these questions are duplicates, but I noticed that the moderator did not go back and mark any of the questions as duplicates. So hasn't the moderator done a disservice? If the moderator is not going to mark a duplicate, then it seems they are just removing potentially valid answers.

I have seen suggested before that "Well, a moderator may not be an expert in the subject of the question". OK yeah, maybe that true. But couldn't they get the ball rolling? Couldn't the moderator flag all the involved questions as duplicates, and then if enough other voters agree, the question will be closed? With the current status quo, the questions don't even enter review, only the answers do.

Comment: the real question is why *you* don't vote to close as duplicate since your are duplicating the same answer into different questions?

Comment: How does _“So the moderator believes that these questions are duplicates”_ follow from _“If the question is not a duplicate, \[…\]”_?

Comment: In order to flag something as duplicate, you need a dupe target. Meaning that you must be able to tell which question is the best one to preserve - it is not necessarily the oldest one. This requires domain knowledge and a moderator might not necessarily have that.

Comment: **If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can chime in here a bit too, as an elected mod that processed *quite a few* of these types of flags.

If an *identical* answer honestly applies to five different questions, the following things are probably true:

- The best question out of the lot should probably be selected as a canonical
- The remaining questions should probably be marked as duplicates of the canonical, and curated since they'll be sign posts
- Subject matter experts (which aren't always diamond moderators) should consider the idea of *merging* those questions into one canonical, even though it means taking on the responsibility of cleaning up the final artifact. Mods need to help here, and can, because they're putting what a group of folks decided into action.

You don't want *one* person orchestrating this with their own judgement, even if they have the domain knowledge required to have a good opinion on how it should end up. Now, we don't have tools that help mods package this up and drop it on meta more deliberately (though it is sometimes picked up in review) -- we definitely need to fix that.

But, guiding users to mark the duplicates and recognize that there's more to look at is an essential first step - if the community doesn't know they can't help.

Answer (score 42):

*I'm answering here as the moderator that handled your posts, but the following is the general policy all moderators follow.*

Nowhere in the message is it stated we believe the question to be duplicates. We *infer*, from  your actions, that **you** believe the questions to be related enough that you copied your answer across to each, and want you to rethink your actions.

**The aim is to teach the answerer to use duplicate voting, rather than copy-pasting.**

Moderators don’t usually make a call on the technical aspects of every post we handle. Just because someone posted a copied answer to several questions does not mean that the author of the answer was copying them to questions that are actually duplicates. Figuring out that posts really are duplicates is a task we need the community to take responsibility for. Moderators are the *exception handlers*, doing the work the community *can't* do. So, our votes are *binding*, we don't get to shift the buck back to the community by pushing questions into the review queue.

In other words, *you* should use duplicate voting here.

Had these questions been in tags that cover my own areas of expertise, I might have voted to close as duplicates. Had the answers been marked accepted (or copied across from a self-answered question), I often do take that as a stronger signal that the questions are indeed duplicates. But generally speaking, moderators won't make that call, because our close votes are binding.

Comment: @StevenPenny: You as the poster of the answers obviously know much more about the subject than a random moderator. I don't know the first thing about, say, C++ templates or R dataframes. Correlation is not causation, and we also see plenty of copying that is just wrong (usually self-promotion of a library the answerer wrote and is now copying to every question that has a single keyword in it). So no, this is not a policy that is going to change.

Comment: I’m just trying to manage expectations here, Steven.

Comment: @StevenPenny [Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/). When a question is closed as a duplicate, it doesn't say "This question is a duplicate of this question", but "This question already has answers here". If it has the same answer, it's a duplicate. The point is to have a many questions => 1 answer thread relation

Comment: @StevenPenny It's not a strong correlation. If the answer to two questions are the same, then the questions are very similar. It's called transitivity.

Answer (score 23):

No, moderators' close votes are binding, and therefore we leave the judging of duplicate questions to the community.

What you should have done instead is to customise your answer to each individual question you were answering instead of copying and pasting the same answer to several similar questions.

The canned comment also informs you (since obviously you know enough about the topic to be able to answer them), to see if you could vote to close those questions as a duplicate of each other if possible. By posting duplicate answers and inaction of not voting to close those questions as duplicates, does the community a disservice instead -- don't blame the mods when you saw the questions first and could have done it yourself to push the questions into the close review queue.

Comment: As you probably know, the close queue is dead and items are often abandoned and dequeued.

Comment: While obviously OP was obviously misbehaving in that particular situation, but just to make clear, a mod that has a gold badge in some tag, lets say javascript (such as yourself), can't close a dupe as an expert on that specific tag? Or you were just addressing this specific case, when you as a mod, obviously shouldn't close those linked questions as dupes?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: see my answer: yes, if I come upon questions where I do have expertise (Python, usually), I'll dupe-close if applicable and I have the time. That's the exception however, and I do so with my Python-gold-badge hat on, not my moderator hat.

Comment: @Daniil: less so now with the lower threshold, and that's no reason to shift the responsibility to moderators. We do not have magical powers of expertise in all subject areas.

Comment: connected-ping @MartijnPieters - Speaking about question closing: How deep is that *binding* you both cited? - I know when you as moderator use the dupe hammer (or close hammer in general), no two other user (as usual) are required to vote to close. You have the overpower (I think similar to a gold badge user in one of the assigned tags, if I remember correctly). The post immediately gets closed. Can I vote to reopen if I wanted to or is it the question post then (b)locked from being opened up again because you as moderator decided it to be closed?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio moderator closure does not block reopening. That only applies to moderator post deletion.

Comment: Re *"We do not have magical powers of expertise in all subject areas."*: [I’m shocked, shocked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUIKWo9PfW0&t=12s).

Comment: @PeterMortensen if only the croupier would walk up right after, with my matrix-style expertise-in-random-subject programme! *Sir, your magical powers of expertise, sir?*

Answer (score -7):

I am clearly in the minority on this topic, but I have always lived by the rule
that if you are in a hole, keep digging! To that end, I would like to note
this. I went back today to the 4 question where answers were deleted, and none
of the questions have been changed at all.

At this time 712 people have viewed my meta question here, 49 people have
downvoted my question here, and 11 have upvoted. Of all those people (not to
mention the moderator in my original question) none have taken any action on
any of those questions. No one has bothered to flag a duplicate, do edits,
tagging, nothing. The obvious retort to this would be "well, Steven Penny, why
don’t *you* do something". That’s true, I could go myself and start the process.
But the point I am trying to make is this:

I think the moderator actions on those questions were a **net negative**. Before
the moderator action, all 5 questions had an additional potentially helpful
answer. After the moderator action, 4 of the questions have one less
potentially helpful answer. And a year from now, those 4 questions will likely
still be sitting there in the same state.

While my initial actions were not the best, *they were something*. These 5
questions are essentially the same. Instead of recognizing that fact, and taking
some step to resolve it, the moderator *took no steps*, and merely reverted
the state of the posts.

That just seems wrong. It would be like if I crashed my car into someone else,
seriously injuring them. Then a cop comes along (moderator) and arrests me, but
then just leaves the other people to their injuries. The moderator in this
situation **knows that likely these questions are duplicates**, but is doing
literally nothing with that knowledge.

Comment: If moderators votes are binding, the least a mod could do after deleting, is probably add a comment under the question: ``"May be related: [link to other answer]"``

Comment: I don't agree that contributing copy-and-pasted answers to the site is a net positive. It may or may not make each of the individual questions better if viewed in isolation, but the more answers each question has, and the more unlinked duplicates of the same question the site has, the harder it is to track down a comprehensive view of a particular problem.

Comment: 1) tailor your answer to the question, 2) moderators are not always subject matter experts. It's that simple.

Comment: "The moderator in this situation knows that likely these questions are duplicates" Do they? Looking at the first two, I don't know nearly enough about PHP to tell at a quick glance, and moderators have way too much work on their plates to spend that much time on tasks that the community can handle without them.